# Semi grid/dynamic columns objects in longlistselector

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, silverlight-5.0

I'm trying to make a longlistselector that looks something like this (different color different type of object):

[image: ...]

The problem however is that all my objects stacks like the blue ones (red and green object gets placed on the same row too). I only want the blue objects to do that. The rest of the objects should have their own row.
Is there any way to accomplish this?

I've been looking at WrapPanel but that didn't seem to work in WP8

My code:

```
<phone:LongListSelector LayoutMode="Grid" IsGroupingEnabled="False" GridCellSize="200,60" Width="Auto" Height="600" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="ListBoxMatchHistory">
  <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <datatemplate:ListboxTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}">
        <datatemplate:ListboxTemplateSelector.Player>
          <DataTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Vertical" ItemWidth="250" ItemHeight="60">
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="250" Height="40">
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=Hero.Image}" Stretch="None"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding account_id}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
              </StackPanel>
            </toolkit:WrapPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
        </datatemplate:ListboxTemplateSelector.Player>
        <datatemplate:ListboxTemplateSelector.ResultShort>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding status}" Width="400"/>
          </DataTemplate>
        </datatemplate:ListboxTemplateSelector.ResultShort>
        <datatemplate:ListboxTemplateSelector.MatchDetailsShort>
          <DataTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Vertical" ItemWidth="400" ItemHeight="30">
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="400">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MatchId}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LobbyType}"/>
              </StackPanel>
            </toolkit:WrapPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
        </datatemplate:ListboxTemplateSelector.MatchDetailsShort>
      </datatemplate:ListboxTemplateSelector>
    </DataTemplate>
  </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Answered similar question but for WP7 that should still apply as seen here = 
 [How do I show multiple columns in a LongListSelector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407430/how-do-i-show-multiple-columns-in-a-longlistselector/16407856#16407856)