# How do I show multiple columns in a LongListSelector?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, longlistselector

How does one get a LongListSelector to show items in multiple columns?

Suppose that three "items" are enough to fill the screen vertically but there is still enough room horizontally for another column. Instead of:

```
item1
item2
item3
... (scroll down)
item4
item5
item6
... (scroll down)
item7
```

I want to see:

```
item1 item5
item2 item6
item3 item7
...(scroll down)
item4
```

I'm guessing I need to introduce a WrapPanel somewhere, but not sure how? Looking for a XAML solution.

We are using item groups, but don't require any special grouping in terms of the columns. In other words, the group headers can appear inline with the items; they don't need to span columns. A given group need not belong to the same column or same screen.

We are building against WP7 so we're using the WP7 Toolkit's version of LongListSelector, not the fuller-featured WP8 version whose LayoutMode solves this easily!

**Update:** Per Chris W's answer I downloaded and built my "own" WP7 toolkit, modifying Generic.xaml as follows:

```
                    <primitives:TemplatedListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <controls:WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </primitives:TemplatedListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

But the items are not wrapping, despite restricting width of datatemplate item to ensure there's room for a second column.

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344938/list-items-vertically-on-a-wrappanel-and-take-advantage-of-multiple-columns) it seems I have to set the WrapPanel's height explicitly to get the desired behavior. I tried hard-coding the WrapPanel's Height as well as MaxHeight just to see if this would work (not a viable permanent solution), but it didn't work either!

Since we don't need the "jump to group" functionality of LongListSelector (we chose it only to do item groupings), I may simply use a [ListBox with a ValueConverter to enable grouping](http://weblogs.asp.net/uruit/archive/2011/06/17/grouping-items-in-a-silverlight-listbox.aspx).